Apache Druid kubernetes operator is failing after adding auth settings
Druid version: 29.0.0.
After adding the standard config from docs to the common.properties config, using Kubernetes operator I get this error in each pod except coordinator:
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Input does not start with Smile format header (first byte = 0x3c) and parser has REQUIRE_HEADER enabled: can not parse
Sample part of config which was added
# Druid basic security
druid.auth.authenticatorChain=["MyBasicMetadataAuthenticator"]
druid.auth.authenticator.MyBasicMetadataAuthenticator.type=basic

# Default password for 'admin' user, should be changed for production.
druid.auth.authenticator.MyBasicMetadataAuthenticator.initialAdminPassword=password1

# Default password for internal 'druid_system' user, should be changed for production.
druid.auth.authenticator.MyBasicMetadataAuthenticator.initialInternalClientPassword=password2

# Uses the metadata store for storing users.
# You can use the authentication API to create new users and grant permissions
druid.auth.authenticator.MyBasicMetadataAuthenticator.credentialsValidator.type=metadata

# If true and if the request credential doesn't exist in this credentials store,
# the request will proceed to next Authenticator in the chain.
druid.auth.authenticator.MyBasicMetadataAuthenticator.skipOnFailure=false

druid.auth.authenticator.MyBasicMetadataAuthenticator.authorizerName=MyBasicMetadataAuthorizer

# Escalator
druid.escalator.type=basic
druid.escalator.internalClientUsername=druid_system
druid.escalator.internalClientPassword=password2
druid.escalator.authorizerName=MyBasicMetadataAuthorizer

druid.auth.authorizers=["MyBasicMetadataAuthorizer"]

druid.auth.authorizer.MyBasicMetadataAuthorizer.type=basic

